# How to add links to other apps working with markdown?

Tags: python, django, markdown

I have a project with 2 apps: **main** and **articles**.

**main** contains some products (the Product model) and it's linked to project's main url (i.e.  'main.urls') so if you type *example.com/products/best-product* you'll go (via slug) to this product view. No need to add .../main/...

**articles** app is like blog app that under *example.com/articles/art-1* you'll see obviously some Article object. It is rendered with **markdown** by markdown() function defined in markdown_extras.py

Now, what I want to do is inside any Article have links to any Product objects. It's trivial without markdown: `{% url 'main:product' prod_obj.slug %}` but how to do this with markdown?

Ideally the syntax (considering different target models) would be:

`I recommend [this product](main:product best-product) for you.`

I tried with basic syntax but any link leads to `example.com/articles/art-1/name`

So containing: app name, target model, slug/id.

I've found some solutions but mostly for external links or internal (this page, not this django project).